# "How would you use the ls command to display all of the files/directories in the directory ‘/sbin’ that start with ‘az’? "

Tags: ls

I could do this on my own if I was in the /sbin directory, but I cant seem to figure out how to do this form the parent directory.

Comment: Try this: ls -ld az*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do:

`ls /sbin | grep '^az.*'`

Comment: Thank you, I was confused on how to combine ls and grep, or if you even need to. :)